# Ignoring single PHPCS rule when running from command line

Tags: phpcs

**Scenario**

Some times, I want to run PHPCS, but have it ignore one rule, in this case the Camel Case Method Name rule.

I know that I can create a new ruleset which inherits all from another ruleset, and excludes one, but I'd like to do this from the command line if possible.

**Question**

When running `phpcs --standard=PSR2 --extentions=php src/`, is there a way to exclude a single rule from the standard for this run?

Comment: There is no way to currently do this. The CLI only allows you to selectively include sniffs and not to exclude them. But it's a good idea for a feature. You should consider adding an issue here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of June 29th, 2016, this is now possible.

To exclude specific sniffs, use the flag `--exclude=sniff1,sniff2,sniff3`.

For more information, see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/904) and [commit](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/commit/c287c99060fbe7f94bd685b4d847113714f239c5).

Comment: To find out the sniff names: `phpcs -e` will list the sniffs, so that you can copy-and-paste them to the `--exclude` argument.